# Query mongodb with C# driver not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following error when pasting examples from the internet to query our mongodb and look for a field.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, think I'll go back to SQL if I can't work it out soon :(

I just want to be able to say find me the cars with 3 doors.

Thanks for any help!  Much appreciated.

**Connection code**

```
public MongoDatabase GetDatabase
{
    get
    {
        MongoClient mc = new MongoClient();
        var server = mc.GetServer();
        return server.GetDatabase("players");
    }
 }
```

**Code sample**

```
var numberOfDoors = 3;

var collection = GetDatabase.GetCollection<CarCollection>("Cars");

// Have tried using my Car object instead of BsonDocument but little difference
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("NumberOfDoors", numberOfDoors);

var result = collection.Find(filter);
```

**Error message**

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery'
```

**Document structure**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "Members" : [ 
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "",
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "",
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

**C# structure**

```
public class MemberCollection
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public MemberEntity[] Members { get; set; }
}

public class MemberEntity
{
    public int _id { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Update - showing error message**

[image]

**Document structure**

[image]

**Update #2**

[image]

**Update 3**

[image]

Comment: FWIW: Make sure you don't actually store passwords in plaintext in your production database.

Comment: of course, this is just a POC but thanks

Comment: @Jamie - Have you find any solution. I am having exactly same problem. btw. i am using 2.5.0 version of mongodb net driver.

Answer (score 5):

Your below line is wrong

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("NumberOfDoors", numberOfDoors);
```

It rather should be below since you are trying to place a filter on `CarCollection`. That's the source of error.

```
Builders<CarCollection>.Filter.Eq("NumberOfDoors", numberOfDoors);
```

Per your recent edit, you should change the filter definition to below since you are actually trying to place a filter on a nested array of `member` objects

```
var filter = Builders<MemberCollection>.Filter.Eq("Members.EmailAddress", emailAddress);
```

The equivalent MongoDB query would be

```
db.Getcollection('Members').Find({"Members.EmailAddress": "test@msn.com"})
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure what's wrong @ your end but give it a try like below

```
var collection = _mongoclientProvider.GetDatabase.GetCollection<MemberCollection>("Members");
Expression<Func<MemberCollection, bool>> expression = mc => mc.Members.Any(m => m.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
var list = collection.Find(expression).ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use `.Eq(string, string)`!

Comment: have provided a new update, still getting the same problem

Comment: @Jamie, see final edit in answer and let know if that helps.

Comment: @Jamie, change this part `Expression<Func<MemberCollection, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<MemberEntity, bool>>`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Builders<CarCollection>.Filter.Eq()` incorrectly:

```
var numberOfDoors = 3;

var collection = ..GetCollection<CarCollection>("Cars");

var builder = Builders<CarCollection>.Filter;
var filt = builder.Where(car => car.NumberOfDoors == numberOfDoors);
var list = await collection.Find(filt).ToListAsync();
```

This assumes that:

```
public class CarCollection : IEnumerable<Car> { ... }
```

and

```
public class Car { public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; } ... }
```

Comment: thanks, I've removed the await and changed to ToList as the method is currently not using a Task<> call but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @Jamie How are you getting your collection?

Comment: @Jamie See the edit, apologies! Just saw my mistake. The `var filt` line has changed.